# Bootstrap Dropdown with insert text action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap drop down menu which can be used to build the expresssion when clicked on the menu item as shown.
For example the dropdown when clicked it should be inserting the data-value text of the menu item into the textbox
As you see When "Action" is clicked it should insert {{Action}} in the textbox, then the user can type " Hello " and then when he clicks some other item "Something else here" it will insert "{{Something else here}}" in the textbox input.

[image]

I have tried with

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dropdown Suggest</h1>

        <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
              <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use click function to insert data value in input field

```js
$(function(){

  $('.dropdown-item').click(function(){
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    $('.form-control').val(value);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dropdown Suggest</h1>

        <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with segmented dropdown button">
          <div class="input-group-append input-group-sm">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Action}}" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Another action}}" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Something else here}}" href="#">Something else here</a>
              <div role="separator" class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" data-value="{{Separated lin}}" href="#">Separated link</a>                                    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```